# Eclipse Releng tools - None of the selected resources is shared in a team repository

Tags: eclipse

I installed according to this [article](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources/How_to_Use_Eclipse_Copyright_Tool) the Releng Tools so i can generate copyright header.

But when i right click any .java source file and click fix copyright, window with error appears:

> 'Fixing copyrights' has encountered a problem.
>
> None of the selected resources is shared in a team repository

Comment: Since this tool is intended for developers working on Eclipse it may need some special setup.

Comment: It uses the file modification date from the team repository to determine whether the year in the copyright string in a file requires updating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution found based on what **nitind** writed in comment.

1. Go to **Window -> Preferences -> Copyright Tool**
2. Check the box `Always use the default revision year instead of repository lookup`